# How to match and replace image URLs in PHP?

Tags: php

I have URL images such as:

```
https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.jpg
```

I want to replace the capital letters at the end of the URL, i.e. `_KOVW` to be replaced by `_kovw` using PHP.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: See [strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php).

Comment: if I want to replace  [A-Z] to [a-z] then how do I do it?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the comment from 53 minutes ago? Please show some code.

Comment: if I want to replace [A-Z] to [a-z] then you can use `strtolower()`

Comment: if you want to lower case that word alone then use `str_replace('_KOVW',strtolower('_KOVW'),'your_url');`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are easier ways to solve your problem, however this would be one way. This method divides URL images to three groups where second group is the target capitalized letters (e.g., `KOVW`). Then, it lowercases the second group and reconstructs the groups.

#### Script

```
// input image goes here
$capital_image = 'https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.jpg';
// divides original image to three groups 
preg_match_all('/(.+?)([A-Z]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|JPG|png|PNG|gif|GIF)/s', $capital_image, $matches);
// glues the pieces of image and lowercases the target part
$lowercase_image = $matches[1][0] . strtolower($matches[2][0]) . '.' . $matches[3][0];
// print the lowercase image
var_dump($lowercase_image);
```

#### Input Images

```
https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.jpg
https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.jpeg
https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.JPG
https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.png
https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.PNG
https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.gif
https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.GIF
```

#### Output Matches

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(110) "https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(102) "https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "KOVW"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "jpg"
  }
}
```

#### RegEx

You can view or modify its RegEx in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/rxgy17/1).

Comment: It seems to be the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by simply using [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$url = 'https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.jpg';
$new_url = str_replace( '_KOVW', '_kovw', $url );
echo $new_url;
```

If your all URLs have same type of problem you can create a function something like this:

```
function fixFileName( $url ) {

    $old_name = basename( $url ); // extract filename from url
    $new_name = strtolower( $old_name ); // lower case filename
    return str_replace( $old_name, $new_name, $url ); // replace old filename with new filename in url and return
}

// how to call function
$url = 'https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.jpg';
echo fixFileName( $url );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) match the start of the url, then match a non whitespace char 1+ times followed by an underscore and forget what was matched using `\K`.

Then match 1+ times an uppercase char followed by a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is a dot and 1+ times a word character (Or .jpg to match it literally)

```
https?://\S+_\K[A-Z]+(?=\.\w+$)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lXb4oN/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/H8IlN)

For example:

```
$str = "https://media.ex-cdn.com/EXP/media.khoeplus24h.vn/files/f1/Uploaded/lenguyet/2014_11_30/nhom1kienthuc_KOVW.jpg";
$str = preg_replace_callback("~https?://\S+_\K[A-Z]+(?=\.\w+$)~", function ($m){return strtolower($m[0]);} , $str);
echo $str;
```